# undefined local variable or method `current_user'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am building my first Ruby on Rails app (ruby 2.0.0p353) by following the [teamtreehouse.com guide](http://teamtreehouse.com/library/build-a-simple-ruby-on-rails-application).

I am using devise 3.2.2 [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and in application.html.erb I want to use devise's "current_user" in order to display the name of the logged in user.

Here the code where I am using "current_user":

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
      <li><%= link_to current_user.first_name, "#" %></li> 
      <li><%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li> 
    </ul>
```

routes.db:

```
Treebook::Application.routes.draw do
   devise_for :t_busers
   resources :statuses
   root to: 'statuses#index'
end
```

However when running my application I am always getting the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<#<Class:0x007f98b1d0edb8>:0x007f98b1cff6d8>
```

I am getting the same error with other methods of devise. I get the error no matter if I am signed in or not signed out. The sign-up, edit etc. of devise seems to work fine. I have tried putting "before_filter :authenticate_user!" into application_controller.rb as indicated in the documentation of devise but that doesn't work either.

Is there anything I need to do in order to use the helpers of devise in a view?

Comment: have you signed in before using current_user method? how are you using it? can you be a little more specific

Comment: You should include code sample of where your problem seems to be if you want help with it.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the post according to your feedback.

Comment: do you have `devise_for :users` in your routes?

Comment: @juanpastas: Do you mean the routes I can see with "rake routes"? There is no `devise_for :users` in there.

Comment: @juanpastas: and **routes.rb** is empty.

Comment: that's all you need then, maybe.

Comment: @juanpastas, I just checked and routes.db was not empty. I will copy it into my main question.

Comment: Post your User model (or model which is used for users)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your routes file, the helper should be

```
current_t_buser
```

From the documentation of `devise`

> Notice that if your devise model is not called "user" but "member",
>   then the helpers you should use are:
>
> before_filter :authenticate_member!
>
> member_signed_in?
>
> current_member
>
> member_session

Comment: This solved it! thank you! I'm new to rails and I guess I didn't get the phrase "Convention over configuration" when I named my model "TBuser" instead of "user"!

Answer (score 1):

Change your routes file:

```
devise_for :t_busers
```

to:

```
devise_for :users
```

Then you should be able to use `current_user`. This assumes you have a model called `User` with its correspondent table `users`.

Comment: I named my model `TBuser` :-( problem is solved. I need to change the name of the model to `user` or use `current_t_buser`. Thank you!